# Persist combo box data after every submit on Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm filling up a combo box through a table on a database using LINQ2Entities.

After the very first page load, a `OnGest()` comes in to load that combo box with options. From that point, I've got no issues at all.

However, after every time I submit a form, the combo box goes empty. I noticed, that the `OnGest()` was not triggered by that page load.

The code in question:

```cs
public void RetrieveNames(List<String> names)
{
using (RazorDatabaseContext context = new RazorDatabaseContext())
{
    var personDAL = context.People.Select((person =>
                    new { person.Id, person.Name, person.Age, person.Nationality })).ToList();

if (personDAL != null)
{
for (int i = 0; i < personDAL.Count(); i++)
{
String? name = personDAL.ElementAt(i).Name;
if (name != null) names.Add(name);
}
}
}
}

[BindProperty]
public List<String> Names
{
    get { return _Names; }
    set { _Names = value; }
}

[BindProperty]
public Person Person
{
    get { return _Person; }
    set { _Person = value; }
}

public void OnGet()
{
    Person = new Person();
    Names = new List<String>();
    Person.RetrieveNames(Names);
}
```

```html
<form method="post">

<select asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Names))">
    <option value="">Pick One</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Submit"/>

</form>
```

I thought using the Constructor() to fill it up every time, it doesn't work either.

Is there a way to persist controls values after a site is submitted, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass `Model.Names` to `Submit` handler,you can try to add hidden inputs,so that the values will be binded to `List<string> Names`.Here is a simple demo,also,you can set name attribute for `<select></select>`,so that the selected value will be passed to the handler:
cshtml:

```
<form method="post">

    <select name="SelectedName" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Names))">
        <option value="">Pick One</option>
    </select>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Names.Count; i++) { 
        <input hidden name="Names[@i]" value=@Model.Names[i] />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Submit" />

</form>
```

cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public List<string> Names { get; set; }
       

        [BindProperty]
        public Person Person { get; set; }
public void OnGet()
{
    Person = new Person();
    Names = new List<String>();
    Person.RetrieveNames(Names);
}
public IActionResult OnPostSubmit(string SelectedName) {
            return Page();
        }
```

**Another solution:**

```
public IActionResult OnPostSubmit(string SelectedName) {
                Person = new Person();
                Names = new List<String>();
                Person.RetrieveNames(Names);
                return Page();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I've been developing for quite a while on WebForms. Had to update to Razor Pages, cause, WebForms are deprecated, nowadays. I've been having problems trying to understand how Razor Pages really work. It's so different from WebForms. I appreciate your time. Have a nice day.

Comment: After submitting it. Those Names are not rendered completely in the combo box. Just half of them.

Comment: You can try to  click `F12` and check the request in NetWork,check if the request post all the Names to handler. Or you can set Names in Submit handler with `Person.RetrieveNames(Names);` again.

Comment: The "Another solution" worked. I have a question about that approach. Why did you use a Post to retrieve (Get) the names? Should you have used a Get like method, instead? What is the "IActionResult" for? Is there a way to achieve this by using the Constructor?

Comment: Using post is because you are using `<form method="post">` in your code.And for IActionResult,with this,you can return the razor page in your handler.And for constructor,we seldom using constructor to get data from request.If my answer is helpful,please mark it as an answer,thank you.

Comment: I marked your answer, thanks.  IActionResult, for returning the razor page in the handler? It will return the page after the Post? I'm confused.